# Cant zoom back in chat

Tags: bug, chat

[image]

I'm stuck in a zoom out mode of the chat. How can I fix that?

It happened when I went to the full, desktop site and then went back in mobile mode

I even deleted my cache/cookies, but it is still stuck like that

Comment: Did you ever get this fixed?

Comment: Can't remember how, but I think it just fixed itself a few days later.